How do I add labels to GitHub runners?
I have defined a new github runner. It has a name, and the name automatically becomes a label.
I'd like to add another label to this runner, to use when matching a workflow to a runner.
"The internet" claims that I can "click the runner in the list, then click in the label area to add another label," but this doesn't appear to work.
I can see the Labels section, I can see the one label bubble that copies the name, but there's nowhere I can click to add another label to this runner.
So, how does one add another label to a given github runner?
Here is what I see when attempting to edit a self-hosted runner:

Here is what I see when I edit a github-hosted runner:


From the runner itself, you are forced to do:
C:\actions-runner> .\config.cmd remove
# ^ it will ask for token! if you did not save it, you will have to remove from github UI
C:\actions-runner> .\config.cmd

From github runners web interface you can add labels for already configured runners:

click on the runner name in the UI
click on the cogwheel to edit labels, see below:



That looks very different from what I see when I edit a runner.
